# How do I receive incoming Google Voice calls using Empathy?

Tags: empathy, google-talk, voip, sip

I have a google voice number so I can receive phone calls dialed to an actual phone number when I'm logged into gmail (via the gtalk widget sidebar).

I see I can use Empathy to make voice calls with other gtalk users.

Is it possible that I can receive phone calls when logged into Empathy, ie, that someone dial my google voice phone number, and it pops up as a call when I'm logged into empathy, the same way it does in the gtalk sidebar widget?

(Currently, I route my gtalk calls to skype, but it would be even better if this worked seamlessly within Empathy.)

Comment: i believe the last poster misunderstood the question. i just tried this and i am NOT receiving notification of an incoming call thru my google VOICE number(not through the gtalk service. talk and voice are 2 completely different beasts.) i'd be happy for any kind of solution at this point that DOESN'T require that i have my browser open to gamil.com, or running an asterisk PBX server, a callback plugin, or require a sip account somewhere...i want to make and receive direct voice calls through my google voice number.

Comment: @seekingsame Um, do you have a sprint number? I do this all the time (as I said in my answer), and my calls show up as being from my Google voice number.

Answer (score 5):

I do this somewhat frequently. To set it up, I did the following:

- Went into Google Voice settings, phone tab.

Made sure it was checked:

[image]

And then I was done! I do recommend that you test your audio in Empathy before doing calls on it all the time, because getting audio to work can *sometimes* be a little tricky, but I haven't had a problem on 12.04 so far.

happy calling!

Comment: This isn't working for me.  Calls still don't notify me in empathy, but works still in gmail.

Comment: @Mittenchops weird... worked fine for me.

Comment: I am able to receive GV calls using Pidgin in the same way as well.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Should we point to the google voice plugin or something? What version of empathy does this work on? I have ubuntu 12.04 also and am not getting notified of calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this trick to use Google voice number in Empathy for both make and receive free calls. I tested it on Ubuntu 12.10 and it's working fine!
http://dailylifetipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2012/10/google-voice-setup-for-voipsip-to-use.html