# Accept Google Voice incoming calls with Empathy (or any other chat) on 13.04

Tags: empathy

I have tried [How do I receive incoming Google Voice calls using Empathy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108634/how-do-i-receive-incoming-google-voice-calls-using-empathy) and [How do I set up SIP voice calling in Empathy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37556/how-do-i-set-up-sip-voice-calling-in-empathy), but nothing works on 13.04.

I don't want to store my login information on another site, so [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/211114/128334) is out.

How can I accept incoming Google Voice phone calls with an Ubuntu app on 13.04?  I'm currently using Empathy but will gladly use anything that prevents having to use a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do audio/video call for XMPP procotol, I am not aware of what google voice uses but surely is not XMPP.

I also have notice since the google+ stuff and gtak becoming hangouts I can no longer make phone/video calls to my google contacts with Pidgin.

Comment: Hmmm, thank-you!  Do you know of another service that provides a free phone number?  I'm 100% committed to Ubuntu now, so if someone doesn't respect linux, I quickly seek alternatives.  Sad goog wants to go this way.  :(

Comment: Ekiga supports SIP if that helps

Comment: I believe empathy also supports SIP, haven't used it in a while.